# Add additional fields in Drupal 8 node edit form

Tags: 8

With the functionality of core drupal 8 module I could view, edit nodes. But what I need is that I need to add some extra fields to the node edit  form. Is there any method to do this ? Any help?

Comment: Can you please be more precise about what do you want? Please write down your use case, so we now better how to help you.

Answer (score 2):

You can add fields to nodes both utilizing the UI and programatically.

To do it over the interface, go Structure > Content Types (in the admin menu) - you will see a list of all node types currently available to your site. Find the node type you want to add fields to and hit 'manage fields' (preselected in the dropdown button to the right).

Now you can use 'add field' to add fields of any type you have enabled/downloaded from drupal. (If you don't have a whole lot of field types to select from, check if their modules are enabled under 'Extend'.)